# Id vs reference in entity class with persistence

Tags: java, oop, entity, persistence, class-design

This is a purely theoretical question. Let's say I have an entity Foo linked to an other entity Bar. Obviously both are assigned a unique id, which is used by the persistence system to link them. Should my Foo entity class have a reference to a Bar object or a Bar object id? In code :

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    Bar bar;
}
```

or

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    int barId;
}
```

This is a pretty basic problem but I wasn't able to find a satisfying answer. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505305/class-design-entity-id-vs-entity-reference) has very few insights.

The way I see it is that using reference is more along the OOP philosophy but could easily generate null references and performance problems without the use of lazy loading. On the other hand, using id would be faster and easier but could quickly lead to inconsistent data.

So what should one do and why?

- Always use id
- Always use reference
- Depends of the model

If it depends, are there decision factors like entity size, "depth", model complexity...? Or is it only a matter of testing both?

Also could someone point me to some literature reference about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that I always need the foreign key so at a minimum, I need:

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    int barId;
}
```

Including a reference to Bar depends upon the application. If you are using an ORM, then Foo can have Bar reference as a direct or lazy relationship:

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    int barId;
    Bar bar;
}
```

Comment: Since Bar has an id field too, having a Bar reference instead of its id is also a valid solution to store the foreign key (lazy loading can't be used in that case).
Having both its id and a reference in Foo seems redundant, doesn't it? Why bother adding a reference if you can access it with the id?

Comment: basbodart, I understand you point. It depends upon the ORM that you use. If the ORM can use the foreign key in bar, then barId is not needed.

Comment: I don't use one actually. Anyway that is irrelevant, an ORM implementation would need to face this problem too.